# Better way of inserting numbers into an array while sorting it

Tags: c#, sorting

Let's say I want to insert values into an array while at the same time sorting it.
This was my solution:

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
int  k;
arr[0] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (k = i; k > 0 && num < arr[k - 1];--k) arr[k] = arr[k - 1];

    arr[k] = num;
}
```

I know I didn't handle exceptions, I'm just talking about the code itself.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What would be your input and how do you want it to be sorted? It would help us answering if you would provide the preferred output

Comment: What do you mean by better? Performance wise or in terms of readability?

Comment: Usin a list object would be better than an array.  There are more methods in a list.  Also how do you sort an array of 5 items when you have only two items in the array?  Do the 3 empty items sort to the beginning or end of the array?

Comment: @jdweng its sorted from the lowest to the highest number. this code startes placing the numbers from the right side i.e the 0 index and so on and whenever a new item is placed it checks where it needs to be inserted,moves the array the the right side and places itself there. a list would be more practical if i dont have a cpecific amount of numbers i want to be inserted.

Comment: @CSharpie to either shorten the code or just make it better preformence wise

Comment: @bas from the smallest being on the 0 index to the highest at the last index

Comment: Do you **have** to insert it in the right place at the time of registration? Can't you just collect all the numbers first, and **then** sort them? If you absolutely need to do this then I would implement a skip-list and binary search, or a tree-structure (not an array). Everything else will be inefficient.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes is has to be inserted at the right place each time its inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [SortedSet<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx), that gets automatically sorted as you add items.

```
var numbers = new SortedSet<int>()
{
    4,
    9,
    6,
    3
};

foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be array you could do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 List<int> list = new List<int>
  {
    1,
    2,
    7,
    10
  };

  int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  list.Add(k);
  list.Sort();
}
```

Edit: if you want to sort when inserting you could do this:

```
 int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  int i = list.Where(x => x > k).Min();
  int index = list.IndexOf(i);
  list.Insert(index, k);
```

Comment: well i want it sorted while its being inserted not after

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List` and convert it into an array. When you maintain your list ordered at all time you can use the list's `BinarySearch` method to get the insert index:

```
const int length = 5;

List<int> result = new List<int>(length);

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int insertIndex = result.BinarySearch(num);
    if (insertIndex < 0) {
        insertIndex = ~insertIndex;
    }
    result.Insert(insertIndex, num);
}
int[] arr = result.ToArray();
```

The binary search is *much* faster than the linear search you are currently performing. You won't see that with your current 5 values. You would defenitely see it with larger lists (hundrets or thousands of values).